# php link to page from users role type

Tags: php, wordpress, printf

I am trying to make a link for user to navigate to, when they are displayed what group they belong to:

```
<?php $user = wp_get_current_user();?>
<a href="#"><?php printf( '%s.', $user->roles[0] );?></a>
```

Very nicely the code echos what role (group) the user belongs to, now i just need it to be a link to the corresponding page (same name as the user role)

e.g "You are in group Alpha" (where Alpha needs to be a link to the page Alpha)

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`href="#"` is what you need to change.

for example:

```
    <?php $user = wp_get_current_user();?>
    <a href="http://example.com/<php echo $user->roles[0];?>"><?php printf( '%s.', $user->roles[0] );?></a>
```

or if you need to use `printf`:

```
    <?php $user = wp_get_current_user();?>
    <a href="http://example.com/<?php printf('%s',$user->roles[0]);?>"><?php printf( '%s.', $user->roles[0] );?></a>
```

or even:

```
    <?php $user = wp_get_current_user();?>
    <a href="http://example.com/<?php printf($user->roles[0]);?>"><?php printf( '%s.', $user->roles[0] );?></a>
```

but `echo` is totally enough in your case.

---

Please note, that this is a basic knowledge about `HTML`, and before programming in `PHP` you should consider learning that first.